# Image gallery with thumbnails from database, each related to other images

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've searched a lot of material here and elsewhere on the web about thumbnail images linking to image gallery, but I think I'm missing something simple and hope you can help.  The use chooses a set of thumbnail images to display based on a button click.  I retrieve the thumbnails from a mysql database.  So far, so good. On clicking a thumbnail, I want to display multiple other images related to that thumbnail and for this, I'm using a jquery script like so:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function(){
         $( "img" ).on("click",function(){
            var $thumb_name = $("img").attr("src");
            $.ajax({
                  type:"post",
                  url: "test.php",
                  data: {thumb_name:'$thumb_name'},
                  success: function( data ) {
           $( "#val" ).html(data);
           } //data
    }); //close ajax
    }); //close onclick
    }); //close document ready
    </script>
```

The server side php script is simply

```
    <?php
        $thumb_name = $_POST['thumb_name'];
        echo "the clicked thumb is $thumb_name";
    ?>
```

I've retrieved $thumb_name from the database (I can display it/them alongside the thumbnail images).  The problem is that the code above doesn't pass it to the server side as a value but rather as the string $thumb_name. I'm communicating with the php script because the string does get placed in the div named 'val'.  I know how to display the further images if I can get the thumbnail image's actual name.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the quotes around `$thumb_name`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $( "img" ).on("click",function(){
        var thumb = $(this).attr("src");
        $.ajax({
              type:"post",
              url: "test.php",
              data: {thumb_name: $thumb_name},
              success: function( data ) {
       $( "#val" ).html(data);
       } //data
     }); //close ajax
   }); //close onclick
}); //close document ready
</script>
```

Comment: Well spotted, Fabian.  I thought I'd tried that but apparently not.  Green check for you--thanks!

Comment: @Fabian--if you're still there, I have a small problem with the script.  If there are multiple thumbnails, the scripts only return the name of the first one, no matter which is clicked.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JoeJohnson You need to use `this` inside your function, check my edit. If you don't, `$('img')` returns an array of all images on the page which is not what you want in that case.